# ¿Porqué no se ve el icono en mi página web?

Tags: html5, web

Buenas acabo de subir mi pagina (hosting) y el icono no se ve ya repare lo de los logos y otras cosas que no se veían; ahora, el icono no se ve esta el nombre bien la ruta bien, no se cual pueda ser el problema.
Les dejo esa porción de código:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/slider.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="estilo/estilisado.css" type="text/css"/>
    **<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logos/cuervo.ico">**
    <head manifest="/manifiesto/manifiesto.cache">
        <title>Dark Page</title>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logos/logo.png">
        </div>
```

Comment: que error te marca ?

Comment: la verdad es que no me marca ningún error solamente no aparece el icono igual me pasaba con otras imágenes y logos y con arreglar las mayúsculas y las minúsculas ya estaba solucionado solamente el icono es el que no me aparece; aparece cuando hago la prueba de escritorio pero en la red no. te puedo dar el link de mi pagina no es la gran cosa pero es un logro mio jaja

Comment: Si visitas la URL de tu página por ejemplo, `example.com/logos/cuervo.ico` te aparece el ícono o un error 404?

Comment: Gracias ya esta resuelto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero en primer lugar que borres la caché de tu navegador. Sobre todo archivos e imágenes que se almacenan en caché.

En segundo lugar, veo más útil utilizar un icono en png, por el fondo transparente.

```
<link rel=icon href='img/icono.png' sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
```

Comment: Gracias Jok, haré lo que me dijiste a ver que pasa, gracias.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ahora si se ve todo normal gracias mil!!!

Comment: Valora la pregunta y márcala como que ha solucionado tu pregunta!

Comment: Disculpa como hago para valorarla y marcarla de solucionada, gracias.